# The semantics of **ASTERISK variable** in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

I know the structure *var

```
def fn(*var):
  pass
```

which if the analoguous of `.` var of `scheme` or va_args of `c`.

Now I met the amazing structure

```
def fn(**list):
  pass
```

which is useful to pass to fn the names of variables and values, as a dictionary (with no analogous in scheme).

Is there some structure in python with 3 asterisks ?

```
def fn (***variable)
```

What is the general meaning of `asterisk` + `variable` in python ?

Comment: Only 1 or 2 asterisks have meaning, which are as you described

Comment: [*args and **kwargs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3394835/1764118)

Comment: thanks. this is useful to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, `*` and `**` have specific meanings, just as you describe. There is no `***` and no general rule that applies to the number of asterisks.

Comment: Could you explain what they are? I'd love to know since I only dabble in Python.

Comment: @ArtB: The best reference is the Python documentation itself, section [5.3.4 Calls](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls).

Comment: **tl;dr** Arguments passed with `*` are passed via an anonymous tuple, and arguments passed with `**` are passed via an anonymous map.